# How to fetch data from website when it does not exist in HTML doc

Tags: php

I want to fetch all current and future data about clan members from this website:
https://clashofclans.com/clans/clan?clanTag=YC22JUC8
They don't have an API. I try use HTMLDOM but I can't find this data.

There is only this:

```
<div class="ClanDetails-MemberResults" data-reactid=".qbqzxvotts.0.4">
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site have an ajax call, so https://clashofclans.com/clans/clan?clanTag=YC22JUC8 won't work here. Try this one
https://set7z18fgf.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/?route=getClanDetails&clanTag=%23YC22JUC8

with this link you will get some JSON response. Filter what you need.

Comment: Yes this is it. Thank You Very Much

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped you then please mark it as right answer.